# Write function that returns shortest word in a list

Tags: python, list, function

I have made a function that works. However, the output is a bit different than what it should be.

In this assignment I am not allowed to change the print statement, which means that I have tweak the function to print the right result. 
My function :

```
def shortest_word(word_list):
    shortest = word_list[0]
    shortest_lenght = len(shortest)
    for country in word_list:
        if shortest_lenght > len(country):
            shortest_lenght = len(country)
            shortest = country
    return shortest

word_list = ["denmark", "sweden", "germany"]
print(shortest_word(word_list))
```

It should print: `"sweden"`.
However it prints: `sweden` without ""

Comment: The string `"sweden"` does not contain any quotes. Use `word_list = ['"denmark"', '"sweden"', '"germany"']` if you absolutely want that (but I think you don't).

Comment: you don't need `shortest_word` function. Just do `min(word_list, key=len)`

Comment: Thx for the feedback. DeepSpace. I am doing an introductory course to programming and we haven't read about the min method yet, so I do not think I can use that for this assignment, although it looks way nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the `word_list` itself, you could just use the `repr` like,

```
>>> word_list = ["denmark", "sweden", "germany"]
>>> print(word_list[1])
sweden
>>> print(repr(word_list[1]))
'sweden'
```

or if double quotes is a must then,

```
>>> print('"{}"'.format(word_list[1]))
"sweden"
```

Comment: No problem. But may i ask, why they wanted the name in double quotes when printed ?